# Definir un link que se dirija a una region en especifico - ORACLE APEX 5

Tags: oracle, apex

Estoy trabajando con Oracle Apex version 5, y tengo un classic report, en el cual una de las columnas es tipo link, aqui me gustaria que al dar clic sobre la liga te posicione en otra pagina en una region en especifico. Como puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

A continuación los pasos generales para construir el link:

1. Cambiar el tipo de columna del Informe Clásico a Enlace.
2. Ir al grupo Enlace de la columna y definir hacia que página se debe direccionar.
   Ingresar la página, 
   Los elementos que se necesiten configurar (Nombre y valor), 
   Limpiar Cache (el mismo número de la página a la que se direcciona).
   Anclaje, ingresar el Identificador Estático de la región a posicionar.
3. En la página a direcionar, ir a la región que se necesita posicionar. configurar el 
   Identificador Estático que se utilizo en el paso anterior.